# How to add php values inside Apache 2.4 conf instead of creating extra pools with PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, apache

With mod_php this was easy: using php_value, php_admin_value, php_flag etc. But I want to know if this is possible with php-fpm to avoid a lot of redundant lines and configuration files or pools.

Based on some other topics I found this example

```
SetEnv PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "post_max_size = 8M"
```

but setting multiple values will not work, only the last rule will be processed. E.g.

```
SetEnv PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "post_max_size = 8M"
SetEnv PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "memory_limit = 256M"
SetEnv PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir = /some/custom/path/"
```

I'm interested to add these to apache configuration, not on user basis like .htaccess or .user.ini. Does anybody have a solution? Thank you!

Comment: I found this Googling for the same issue 1yr+ later. Could you please post the solution?

Comment: Setting up multiple PHP_ADMIN_VALUE values is not working with SetEnv or similar. You can set just one (e.g. open_basedir) at the same time. And "SetEnv PHP_ADMIN_VALUE" is very risky and in no way recommended. One can alter its value, leading to arbitrary results. I ended up blocking completely  SetEnv for .htaccess, using separate pools for each user. Restart may take a while if you have too many pools, but you may create more daemons and split configs between them.

Answer (score 0):

Put your php directives into one line and separate them with the ugly vim newline by pressing CTRL+V in write mode and then Enter. Then you will get ^M. Don't copy ^M from here. It will not work.

[image: example]

Comment: Is this "feature" documented anywhere? Or is there an other alternative for inside VHosts setting multiple PHP_ADMIN_VALUEs?